# issue with dropdown menu on samsung phone

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, samsung-mobile

I have a site with a lot of drop downs (I know, that is what client wants). I'm using jquery mobile and responsive design, but I'm having some issues with one of the dropdowns on samsung galaxy S4. By default, when the dropdown is clicked, SGS4 opens its native interface to select one of the options. The problem is that it is way too narrow and all the options are truncated even before the point they starts to differ.

Question is, is there any way we can control how it is being displayed or at least make it x-scrollable?

Comment: is the list long? if not, add `data-native-menu="false"` to `select`. This will convert it into a popup.

Comment: @Omar - thanks a lot, it seems to work just fine. Could you please add it as an answer so I can accept it?